# How to set client credentials for WCF service hosted over basicHttpBinding and referenced as web service from Windows CE?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, windows-ce

I have a Windows CE 5.0 app created in Visual Studio 2008. This app references a service, which is a WCF Service created in Visual Studio 2010 and hosted in IIS 6. Since the service is referenced from a Windows CE project, it is referenced as a legacy web service using the Add Web Reference dialog.

The service is configured to use Transport security and it expects Windows credentials:

```
<system.serviceModel>   
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceTests.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceTests.ITestService" bindingConfiguration="basicConfig"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicConfig">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This service is easily consumed from a normal .net 4.0 app as below:

```
var client = new TestServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "FBradley";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "jgb.2013!";            
System.Console.WriteLine(client.GetData(1));
System.Console.ReadLine();
```

However, from the Windows CE project the ClientCredentials property is not available, only a Credentials property. I have attempted to pass a NetworkCredential type to it but it fails:

```
using (var client = new TestService())
{                           
      client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usename", "password", "domain");
      var response = client.GetData(1, true);
      MessageBox.Show(response);
}
```

Am I leaving out something from the service config file that the Windows CE device (which is obviously not a member of the domain) needs to authenticate? How can I configure this Windows CE (non-domain) device or the service so that the client can consume the service? What am I missing?